# How to make an AJAX call immediately on document loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, initialization

I want to execute an ajax call as soon as a document is loaded. What I am doing is loading a string that contains data that I will use for an autocomplete feature. This is what I have done, but it is not calling the servlet.

I have removed the calls to the various JS scripts to make it clearer. I have done several similar AJAX calls in my code but usually triggered by a click event, I am not sure what the syntax for doing it as soon as the document loads, but I thought this would be it (but it's not):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.dimensions.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.autocomplete.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "AutoComplete",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: queryString,
                success: function(data) {
                        var dataArray = data;
                        alert(dataArray);
                        }
                });

     $("#example").autocomplete(dataArray);
  });
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    API Reference:
<form><input id="example"> (try "C" or "E")</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** my code now looks more like Karim's:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../AutoComplete",
        success: function(data) {
             $("#example").autocomplete(data);
        }
     });
 });
```

Nonetheless the autocomplete still doesn't work (admittedly another question altogether, so I will also post another question so it has an appropriate title).

My variable "data" that is being sent back looks like ... "Manuscript|Text|Information Object|Basketball|Ball|Sporting Equipment|Tarantula".split("|");

If I do

```
var dataArray = "Manuscript|Text|Information Object|Basketball|Ball|Sporting Equipment|Tarantula".split("|");
```

and then

```
$("#example").autocomplete(dataArray);
```

It all works fine, but when I get the value of dataArray from the server it doesn't.

Comment: I have put the <script> tags back in. They are a little verbose, but this is what the W3C validator gave me.

Comment: Looks about right, assuming it's the jQuery link-in that you've skipped for clarity. Is the ajax call maybe failing? What happens if you try hanging the function off the "complete" (or "error") event rather than "success"? Do you get the alert then?

Comment: Thanks Matt, tried those ideas, but didn't get anything different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have jQuery loaded before making calls to the jQuery API.

Before your code snippet, load jQuery...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Yes I have that <script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">

I removed the script tags to make the code clearer - I have used firebug to check that these are all available.

Comment: Then make sure that you are getting back well-formed JSON.

Try getting rid of "DataType" and letting jquery auto detect. At least then you can see if your call is working.

Comment: Also, while debugging, I will often use "complete" instead of "success". That way, again, you can see what the server is spitting out (if anything)

Comment: That didn't work, but I get the feeling it's not how I have designed my code but some config or path that I have gotten wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay. Remember that it will call to the server from the path where the HTML file is sitting. So, if the autocomplete script is back a directory or something, it wont find it. Try plugging in a full URL.

Comment: Thanks Brant, that was exactly one of the problems. However I am also having the problem that Karim noted below. Will update the question.

Answer (score 4):

You're running into that problem because the $.ajax call does *not* return before the autocomplete is initilised, due the the asynchronous nature of XHR. The request is sent, execution flows into the next expression before `dataArray` has been filled up within the `success` callback. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "AutoComplete",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: queryString,
            success: function(data) {
                var dataArray = data;
                alert(dataArray);
                $("#example").autocomplete(dataArray);
            }
        });
});
```

That will ensure that your autocomplete is initialised only when the response from the server has been received.

Comment: Thanks I tried something similar but it still doesn't work, I have asked another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803589/jquery-autocomplete-works-with-a-local-string-but-not-when-the-same-string-is-cal which explains the issue more properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Also make sure that the response is really a JSON. If servlet gives the error, it will not be correctly processed in your case. Use firebug to see if servlet is called and what was the response. Or do minimal logging on the serverside.

Comment: $(document).ready(function (){}); and $(function(){}); are the same thing.  If he wants to run code when the page has finished loading and not when the DOM has finished loading, he needs to use $(document).load

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Chrome Browser developer tools to see what your server is returning. To access pres Ctrl+Shift+I and in the developer tool view, check the network tab to see of any possible error or wrong data coming or not.